# How to trigger CakePHP validation on submission only when certain field is not empty

Tags: cakephp

I've created a form, in which 3 inputs are optional. However, if a user does input either one of those, I hope validation is triggered and ask the user to also fill in the other 2.

The inputs:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('FirstCondition.week'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('FirstCondition.start'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('FirstCondition.end'); ?>
```

Not sure how I can do that?

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: 2.64. Thanks so much.